# Remove null elements from list

Tags: java

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("One");
  list.add(null);
  list.add("Two!");
  list.add(null);
  list.add("Three");
  list.add(null);
  list.add("Four");
  list.add(null);
```

I have a list containing **null** elements. Is there any way to remove the **null** elements from the current collection without using any iterations?

Comment: Without you writing any iterations, or at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819635/how-to-remove-all-null-elements-from-a-arraylist

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This should work:

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: Time complexity of `List.removeAll()` is **n^2**. Just saying.

Comment: @Hermanth Wouldn't the complexity be `n*m` with `m==1` for that singleton?

Answer (score 11):

In java 8 you can use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
list.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Answer (score 5):

Extend `ArrayList` and override `add()` & `addAll()` method and simply don't allow `null`

or you could use `list.removeAll(null);` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819635/how-to-remove-all-null-elements-from-a-arraylist) <sub>Which internally iterates the loop</sub>

Comment: I don't like extending such classes, as it could lead to confusing code. You should also keep in mind that you can also add items to the list with a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on LambdaJ that allows you to manipulate collections "without" loops. Actually the loops are implemented inside the library but it really cool and it simplifies you code and makes it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

not efficient, but works

`while(list.remove(null));`

Answer (score 1):

The current answers don't distinguish the mutable and immutable lists and I find a lot of ways missing. This becomes even more important with `List.of(..)` introduced as of [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), although one [cannot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) pass a `null` element to it. The removal is relevant anyway (ex. removing a certain non-null element).

**Immutable List**

An example of a immutable list is `Arrays.asList(..)` (yet the elements can still be replaced, but not added/removed) or already mentioned `List.of(..)`. These are considered as "immutable wrappers" as long as one cannot add/remove an element using the `List` methods.

```
List<String> immutableList = Arrays.asList("one", null, "two");
```

- [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) as of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) using the `Stream#filter(Predicate)` method:

  ```
  List<String> newList = immutableList.stream()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- For-each loop either with indices or the enhanced one is suitable (not only) for Java versions [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) and lower.

  ```
  // note we need to create a mutable List to add the non-null elements
  List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String str: immutableList) {
      if (str != null) {
           newList.add(str);
      }
  }
  ```

**Mutable List**

An example of a mutable list is a new instance of the `List` interface such as `new ArrayList<>()` or `new LinkedList<>()`. They are mutable, therefore adding the elements using `List#add` or `List#addAll` is possible and a common way to do so.

```
List<String> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", null, "two"));
```

Here are listed ways to remove all the `null` elements from such `List`. Note it *modifies* the list.

- `List#removeIf(Predicate)` as of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

  ```
  mutableList.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
  ```
- `Iterator` is a recommended way to remove elements from a `List` and is suitable (not only) for Java versions [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) and lower

  ```
  Iterator<String> iterator = mutableList.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      if (iterator.next() == null) {
          iterator.remove();
      }
  }
  ```
- All the ways mentioned in the **Immutable List** section which always results in a new `List`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the list yourself and not sure if the value is null or not you can also use `CollectionUtils.addIgnoreNull(list,elementToAdd);` This will prevent null elements from being added. This only works when constructing the list. If you are receiving the list from somewhere else and want to remove all non-null elements prior to using the list, then the `list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));` will be best

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <array.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.size()-i-1; j++) {
        if (array.get(j) > array.get(j+i)){
            Integer t = array.get(j+i);
            array.set(j+i,array.get(j));
            array.set(j,t);
        }
    }
}

for(int i = array.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
```

Its a ascending order , what will be  descending order of this problem ?

Comment: Questions should be asked on a separate thread. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want to ask your question. Answering a question means answering a question, not asking yet another question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `google.common.`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public List<String> removeBlanks(List<String> list) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list, new Predicate<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(String arg) {
            return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(arg);
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Java Stream to filter out the nullable elements:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```