# Java - Remove null from list of Objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8

I have a huge sized java list object as follows :

```
List<Object[]> res = // repo method that will return query result
```

I have to remove nulls from the res object.

I tried below methods so far but nothing seemed to work:

```
1. res.remove(null);
2. res.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
3. res.removeAll(null);
4. while(res.remove(null));
```

How can I remove nulls efficiently as the list size is going to be huge?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it'll be a lot easier to help you that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was having another issue too that let to this prblem

Comment: In general query results are not guaranteed to be mutable, so you may not be able to do what you are trying. With a mutable list (an `ArrayList` in my case) nos. 2 and 4 work for me (no. 1 removes only the first `null` and no. 3 throws).

Comment: Please, *nothing seemed to work* is not very helpful. Please quote the exact error messages you get so we may help you how to solve them. Or if you don’t get any error messages, specify precisely how observed result differs from the expected. [I downvoted because "it's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Mutable list**

You can use `List::removeIf` with a predicate detecting `null` items.

```
List<Object[]> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Object[] {}, 
    null, 
    new Object[] {}));

mutableList.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

**Immutable list**

In this case you have to use Stream API or a for-loop to find non-null elements and add them to a new list.

```
List<Object[]> immutableList = Arrays.asList(
    new Object[] {}, 
    null, 
    new Object[] {});

List<Object[]> newList = immutableList.stream()
                                      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Very fine answer. And really nitpicking: `Arrays.asList()` doesn’t return a completely immutable list since you may substitute each element in the list (using `set()`). But you are correct, no elements can be removed from the list.

Comment: @OleV.V.: Thank's for the note. The `Arrays.asList()` operates on a fixed-length backing array, so no elements can be added/removed but can be replaced, right?

Comment: Exactly right (and I still think it’s a great answer).

Comment: @OleV.V. I have created a "semi-canonical" answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559257/remove-null-elements-from-list as long as I miss there a lot of ways or the element removal. I believe that one deserves more attention than this one. Preferably, I'd like to remove this answer in favor of the newer one and only refer to it at the comments for sake of getting rid of the "duplicates".

Comment: For other readers: [Link to Nikolas’ new and extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64910701/5772882)