# Size of the list does not match the ones it has

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have a list with 20 elements, but it contains a null value at the 15 position, how can I remove the null value from an `List`?

Comment: Could you post the code used to do this? Then we can make suggestions on how to change it.

Comment: Very unclear question. Are you asking how to remove a null element from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819668/1879661) from @Lithium after some days researching

`tourists.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));`

This code remove all null values from an list.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the 'null' image to appear on a list, just do something like:

```
for each item on a list
    if item == null then continue
    else 
        add an item to <List>Images
```

If you pass a null object to the List of Images, it still does occupy the place in the list, even though this place is technically uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

you can't say `null` value means the object is not exist, even `null` isn't an object in java.

`String s = null` means the reference of `String s` is unset, but the declare is done, an object with String type and called s.

see more detail about it, [oracle doc: The Kinds of Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(null);
    al.add("not null");
    System.out.println(al.size()); //output 2

    //if you wanna know how many objects inside of list and isn't null
    int count=0;
    for(Object obj:al)
        if(!(obj==null)) 
            count++;
    System.out.println(count); //output 1

    System.out.println(al); //output [null, not null] ← null is exist.
}
```

so in you case, the return of size() should be 20.