# Regex for extracting all possible amounts

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will extract all possible amounts from a string, assuming that amounts always contain 2 decimals, and accepting either `.` or `,` liberally as separators. For example, for the following string, I would like to find the amounts below:

```
1.234,567.89

1.23
1.234,56
  234,56
   34,56
    4,56
1.234,567.89
  234,567.89
   34,567.89
    4,567.89
      567.89
       67.89
        7.89
```

Is this achievable with regex?

My current regex is `?\\d{1,3}([\\.,]\\d{3})*([\\.,]\\d{2})` but that obviously doesn't work because it only returns 1 match.

Comment: Once a character appears in a match, it can't be reused in another match.

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @4castle not entiry true, it can, through [Backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), although I agree, not for this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, initially, I thought this cannot be done with regex. I was wrong in assuming so, but this is only possible by removing duplicates and empty strings/nulls.

#### Regex

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DEWysf/1)

```
(?=(\d+[.,]\d{2}))(?=((?:\d+[.,]){2,}?\d{2})?)(?=((?:\d+[.,])+\d{2}))
```

The pattern above contains 3 positive lookaheads. They are as follows:

1. `(?=(\d+[.,]\d{2}))` Ensure the following matches

   - `(\d+[.,]\d{2})` Capture the following into capture group 1. This captures shorter variants like `1.23`.

     - `\d+` Match one or more digits
     - `[.,]` Match either `.` or `,` literally
     - `\d{2}` Match exactly 2 digits
2. `(?=((?:\d+[.,]){2,}?\d{2})?)` Ensure the following matches

   - `((?:\d+[.,]){2,}?\d{2})?` Optionally capture the following into capture group 2. This captures the *in-between* numbers like `1.234,56` where a smaller version and longer version exists at that same location (`1.23` and `1.234,567.89` respectively). If longer number versions are possible, you may need to add more positive lookaheads identical to this one and changing `{2,}` in the following section to `{3,}`, `{4,}`, etc. and add those groups to the `while` loop. If no *in-between* number exists, it'll simply capture the same as the third lookahead (the duplicate is removed in the code).

     - `(?:\d+[.,]){2,}?` Match the following 2 or more times, but as few as possible.

       - `\d+` Match one or more digits
       - `[.,]` Match either `.` or `,` literally
     - `\d{2}` Matches exactly 2 digits
3. `(?=((?:\d+[.,])+\d{2}))` Ensure the following matches

   - `((?:\d+[.,])+\d{2})` Captures the following into capture group 3. This captures longer variants like `1.234,567.89`.

     - `(?:\d+[.,])+` Match the following one or more times

       - `\d+` Match one or more digits
       - `[.,]` Match either `.` or `,` literally
     - `\d{2}` Match exactly 2 digits

#### Code

The code below simply iterates over all the matches and extracts the group values adding them to a `List`. `null` values are then removed from the list using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819668/3600709). The list is then turned into a `Set` to remove duplicates according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203992/3600709) and added back to the (now empty) list.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##dZG7bsIwFIZn8hRWJqdQS4TeKUSoS4ciVWIEBjdxE1PfZDtQhPLsqZ0YVeplcvx9/zn2cXZ4jy@lImJXfLQt5UpqC3YOotpShi6m0S@mSUk@0RLbvCL6X/@KrSVaTKMoZ9gYsMRUnKKBqt8YzYGx2LplL2kBuDNwZTUV5XoLsC5NAlxy0CNgwAzEY5ROrkbXN7fo7j6eOhnaA@Vs@Ea55IoyAmOYzeBmUwzXaLR16yltksQzmD2ccXJKR00WZPbLDs9lceJPC8MC7k5TiPc7aJxz8oUa@9hfdg4wcxFBDmChNT52ag67HivynapMSD1jU3nRZVzoUPkBOHqnooBJ/w4DzBAuCkdLLWsFx0nX7ydO/8aTHje@O/Y/h8s9WTAGnyRjJLdUCoOMuxUjVgooasb6isr4Pj6JWQdcdc4I1vC8C7oK77A6Gks4krVFyo1pmQiVTdS07Rc)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "1.234,567.89";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\d+[.,]\\d{2}))(?=((?:\\d+[.,]){2,}?\\d{2})?)(?=((?:\\d+[.,])+\\d{2}))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();

        while(m.find()) {
            al.add(m.group(1));
            al.add(m.group(2));
            al.add(m.group(3));
        }

        al.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        hs.addAll(al);
        al.clear();
        al.addAll(hs);

        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

#### Result

The numbers in the result below coincide with the OP's list of values (albeit the output looks different, you can confirm by crosschecking both sets of values).

```
[34,567.89, 4,56, 7.89, 234,56, 4,567.89, 1.234,56, 1.23, 1.234,567.89, 34,56, 567.89, 67.89, 234,567.89]
```

Comment: Amazing. Waiting for the explanation :)

Comment: Amazing indeed :D Thx